# Phonegap, Cocoa error 257 - The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation not permitted

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, file-upload

I run into a problem for which I cannot find any solution yet.
I'm using Xcode Version 4.5.1 (4G1004), Cordova-2.5.0, iPhone4S (Ver. 5.0 (9A334))

What I'm trying to do is to send file from local filesystem (/var/mobile/Library/Notes/notes.sqlite) to remote server using

```
var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload("/var/mobile/Library/Notes/notes.sqlite", encodeURI("http://myserver.com/fileUpload.php"), win, fail, null);

function win(r) {
            console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
            console.log("Response = " + r.response);
            console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
        }

        function fail(error) {
            alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
            console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
            console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
        }
```

but it fails with error:

```
Error opening file /var/mobile/Library/Notes/notes.sqlite: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 257.)" UserInfo=0x164070 {NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Library/Notes/notes.sqlite, NSUnderlyingError=0x148670 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation not permitted"}
FileTransferError {
    code = 1;
    source = "/var/mobile/Library/Notes/notes.sqlite";
    target = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/fileUpload.php";
}
```

If I do the same thing with contact image everything works OK.

```
ft.upload("/var/mobile/Applications/367E3D28-2912-4E2B-B798-B49D71F9CAE6/tmp/photo_HHcOG", encodeURI("xxxxxxxxxxx/fileUpload.php"), win, fail, null);
```

I have looked at the archives and the commits but did not find any solution except that it is some kind of permission issue, which I understand from (Cocoa error 257.) error. 
Is there a way to assign permission to file notes.sqlite (I checked permissions (using file manager) for notes.sqlite and are the same as for photo_HHcOG). I think maybe it is not file permission but folder or user permission, because I have tried to change permission to notes.sqlite to write for everybody but with same result.

Does anybody know what could be the issue and whether this has been fixed, and point me into right direction?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From Apple

No, you can't. The **sandbox** is there for a reason.

It means you can only read/create files in your app folder.

Two apps can comunicate using [UIDocumentInteractionController](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?hl=en&tab=ww#hl=en&safe=off&sclient=psy-ab&q=UIDocumentInteractionController%20&oq=UIDocumentInteractionController%20&aq=f&aqi=g4&aql=&gs_l=hp.3..0l4.617438.617438.0.621292.1.1.0.0.0.0.577.577.5-1.1.0...0.0.BV22RO4g1IY&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=357008c06016d30d&biw=1280&bih=696)

but for now not with stock notes app.